# How to make Webstorm keep indent of multi line string literals during reformat

Tags: javascript, webstorm

When creating a directive for angularjs I often keep my templates as string literals. Sometimes the templates span several lines, so I indent them the way I would indent a html file for better readability.

Here is a very simple example

```
template: '<div>' +
              '<div>' +
                  '<input ngModel="myText" type"text">' +
              '</div>' +
              '<div>' +
                  '<button ng-click="ok()">OK</button>' +
               '</div>' +
           '</div>',
```

Unfortunately whenever I reformat the code, Webstorm removes all my hand crafted indents, so the template will look like this:

```
template: '<div>' +
'<div>' +
'<input ngModel="myText" type"text">' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<button ng-click="ok()">OK</button>' +
'</div>' +
'</div>',
```

Is there a setting somewhere or another trick to make Webstorm keep the relative indents in multi line string literals during reformat? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you put the whitespace *inside* the strings?

Comment: You have a syntax error: `'</div>', +`

Comment: @iso Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: @jonrshape Putting the indents inside the string would be a way to achieve this, but this unnecessarily bloats the code (I do not think a minifier would handle this). Therefore this is not an option for me, I am afraid.

Comment: Just wondering, why not place in an HTML file?

Comment: @OmriAharon I like keeping the whole directive in one file. Probably just a personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable special formatter control comments in Preferences | Editor | Code style and then use them in your code to prevent WebStorm from reformatting it:

```
// @formatter:off
    template: '<div>' +
              '<div>' +
                  '<input ngModel="myText" type"text">' +
              '</div>' +
              '<div>' +
                  '<button ng-click="ok()">OK</button>' +
               '</div>' +
           '</div>',
// @formatter:on
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful answer.